# Load xml file with not escaped quotes

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tableofcontents

I have a xml file with table of content. The problem is, that it contains not escaped quotes. How can I load the file and repair this quotes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.toc"?>

<topic label="Main Topic" href="0.2.1.html#0.2.5">
    <topic label="Topic "Sales"" href="0.2.1.html#2.12.3.6"/>
</topic>
```

I know that in the standard stays:

```
In the content of elements, character data is any string of characters which does not contain the start-delimiter of any markup
```

The source doesn't escape the quotes and I cannot change the source. How can I repair the xml file locally?

Comment: This simply isn't valid XML. If I ever had to work on that, I would tell the originator to correct it. Period. If you really want to _repair_ it, you unfortunately cannot use an XML parser, but must do it on your own.

Comment: I already told the originator to correct it, but the problem is, that my code won't be compatible with previous versions of the product. So I have to repair it by myself. Do you know any Tools, that might help me to escape the quotes?

Comment: I do not know of such tools. I think you have to write it yourself. Additionally, I fear that asking for such tools (or libraries) is off-topic for SO.

Comment: The main problem it that it is ambiguous, for example `a="b" c="d"` can be setting a to `b" c=" d` or setting a to `b` and c to `d`.

Comment: Well, there is always "label" and "href" property in a <label> tag. I can do it by myself but I was wondering if there's something, that I can use. And I don'T think, that asking about frameworks/tools is offtopic in SO.

Comment: You might look into running it through a parser like jsoup. I don't know that it will fix it but it does fix other XML format issues.

Comment: @aphex: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @vanje If I interpret your remarks literally, you're saying we can tell the originator how to write code to solve the problem, but we can't tell him that the code has already been written and he can download it. That's patently absurd.

Comment: @Micheal Kay: I think this rule relates only to the question and depends on how the question is formulated. If someone asks explicitly for a library or tool, then he or she should better go to [Software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). But it's ok to recommend a tool or library in an answer to prevent to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @vanje: So my question is not a off-topic in that case.

Comment: @aphex: No, I think your question is not off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call it XML when it isn't.

If you want to process this file you'll need to discover what rules (grammar) it conforms to, and write a parser for that grammar. This may be rather difficult; I suspect the grammar, when you discover it, will be ambiguous and will require infinite lookahead to resolve.

Comment: Broken bike is still a bike, right? What about broken xml? I know it doesn't conform xml, but it is still xml. Do you guys never had the chance to use a broken xml from a source, that can't be fixed? Do you write a parser, or do you look first for a way to repair the format and use the xml frameworks?

Comment: @aphex I have seen too many systems that have turned into an unmaintainable mess after a few of such "workarounds". Sometimes the problems surfaced only years after the "fix" was built in and nobody could remember it.

Comment: how do you solve that problem? Let's say we have a broken xml generator, which is delivered to many providers. Now I need to write a new feature, which depends on that. I can fix the broken generator, but the old providers remain with the same, until they upgrade their generator. 

If I support only the new format, the other parties will suffer, that the broken one is not compatible. What would you do in this case?

Comment: You solve the problem by rigorous adherence to standards. Don't tolerate non-conformance; trying to interoperate with stuff that's essentially garbage will always cost you more than it's worth.

Comment: If your stuff is XML, then any random string of characters is XML, and the term XML has ceased to have any meaning. If you must handle it, then the first step is to acknowledge that it is not XML and that XML tools will be of no use to you. The next step is to understand what it actually is: that is, reverse-engineer a language specification that your parser will be written to handle.